# Set of points where sequence converges is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f_n:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, n=1,2,\ldots$ be a sequence of measurable functions. Show that the set of points $x\in X$, where the sequence $\{f_n(x); n=1,2,\ldots\}$ converges, is measurable.

So I get that $g(x)=\limsup f_n(x)$ and $h(x)=\liminf f_n(x)$ are measurable functions.

I want $x$ such that these values are finite, so I take the intersection $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $h^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$, which are measurable sets because $g,h$ are measurable functions.

Now I want $x$ such that these values are equal. I want to define the function $i(x)=g(x)-h(x)$ and take the intersection of the above two sets with $i^{-1}(0)$. But am I allowed to define $i$ like that, since it is possible that $g(x)=\infty$ and $h(x)=-\infty$ (or vice versa)?

Comment: Let $F = \{ x : \lvert g(x)\rvert < \infty, \lvert h(x)\rvert < \infty\}$. Consider $i(x) = \chi_F(x)\cdot g(x) - \chi_F(x)\cdot h(x) + (1 - \chi_F(x))$.