# Set where sequence of functions converges measurable

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, measurable-functions

Let $f_n:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of measurable functions. Show that the set of points, $x\in X$, where the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges is measurable. Then deduce that the set of points, $\omega\in I$, for which the "randomized harmonic series" $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{R_n(\omega)}{n}$ converges is a measurable subset of $I$.

So I know the definition of a measurable function is: for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{x\in X; f(x)>a\}$ is an element of the field. Also, a measurable set corresponds to a Borel set. I just don't know how to get from one to the other.

I've seen the first part of this question posted ([Set of points where sequence converges is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497941/set-of-points-where-sequence-converges-is-measurable)), but it wasn't very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of a monotone sequence of measurable functions is still measurable. Now $\{x\in X:\lim_{n}f_{n}(x)~\text{exists}\}=\{x\in X: \limsup_{n}f_{n}(x)=\liminf_{n}f_{n}(x)\}$. Note that $\limsup_{n}f_{n}=\lim_{n}\sup_{k\geq n}f_{k}$ and $\liminf_{n}f_{n}=\lim_{n}\inf_{k\geq n}f_{k}$.